# Azure mongodb query on nested collection of objects not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDB (mongodb) for storing my data.

I have following documents in my Bucket collection

```
[
    {
        "title":"Bucket1",
        "elementsUsed" : [
            {"elementType" : 1, "count" : 1},
            {"elementType" : 5, "count" : 2},
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"Bucket2",
        "elementsUsed" : [
            {"elementType" : 1, "count" : 1}
        ]
    }
]
```

When I want to find Buckets that have all of specified elementTypes, following query works perfectly on locally installed mongodb instance.

```
Bucket.find({"elementsUsed.elementType": {"$all": [1,5]}})
```

It correctly returns Bucket1.

But when I execute same query on CosmosDB, it returns zero results. Is this a known limitation of CosmosDB?

I searched about CosmosDB limitations but could not find documented.

Comment: Have you tried using '$and` to replace `$all`. Also: are you sure your dbs contain the same values?

Comment: I tried $and just now, it didn't work. I have made sure that my collection has matching documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same operations as yours, no data can be found too. However, based on the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#additional-operators), cosmos db mongo api supposed to support `$all` operator.

I tested it and it works.

***source documents:***

[image]

***Run command:***

```
db.families.find(
    { "Location": { $all: [-121.758, 46.87] } }
)
```

[image]

Per my test and experience, Cosmos DB mongo API does not support all mongo features. I assumed that the `$all` opeartor has not been totally implemented in the Cosmos DB mongo API. Moreover, you could add your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) here to ask for more statements.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: $all works for array of strings, numbers. It is not working for array of objects. I have an array of strings also in my schema. $all query on it works fine. Let me try out the feedback channel. Thanks!

Comment: @PrashantAmbardekar yes,as same as your situation.Waiting for your progress.

Comment: Just to update, I haven't heard from azure folks yet. I have gone ahead and worked around it by adding simplified version (array of numbers) of same collection just for query purpose.

Comment: @PrashantAmbardekar Fine,if you don't mind,you could mark the answer to end this case temporarily .